# Bootstrap columns not same height in iPad portrait mode

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

So portrait mode for this site I'm making is all messed up. Currently looks like this:

[image]

All I want is for the watch to be vertically centered, which it is in normal desktop view.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7  col-xl-7 col-lg-7">
              <div class="header-content">
                  <div class="header-content-inner">
                      <h1>One for all. All for you.</h1>
                      <!-- <a href="#download" class="btn btn-outline btn-xl page-scroll">Start Now for Free!</a> -->
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5  col-xl-5 col-lg-5" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="device-container vertical-align">
              <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="1500" data-cycle-transition="1500" data-cycle-fx="fadeout" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="#er-pauser">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing2.png" alt="">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing1.png" alt="">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing3.png" alt="">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing5.png" alt="">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing4.png" alt="">
                <img class="img-responsive device-img center-block" src="img/landing6.png" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        background: #47c0d7; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #47c0d7 0%, #e6f9ff 55%, #e6f9ff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #47c0d7 0%,#e6f9ff 55%,#e6f9ff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #47c0d7 0%,#e6f9ff 55%,#e6f9ff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#47c0d7', endColorstr='#e6f9ff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    }
    header .header-content {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 100px 0px 0px;
      position: relative;

    }
    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    /*  max-width: 500px;
    */  margin: 0 auto;
    }

    header .device-container {
    /*  max-width: 400px;*/
      height: 100%;
    /*  margin: 100px auto;
    */}

    header .device-img {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 300px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        header {
        min-height: 100%;
      }

      header .header-content {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
      }
      header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 100%;
      }

    .about-content .about-content-inner {
        text-align: justify;
        max-width: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 55px;
        color: #363939;
        text-align: center;
      }
    .about-content .about-content-inner h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      header .device-container {
     /*   max-width: none;
        max-height: calc(0vh);
        margin: 100px auto 0;*/
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
      }
```

The height of the column it's in isn't 100% and the container it's in (device-container) also doesn't appear to hold its contents.

[image][image][image]

Thank you so much for your help. Sorry there's so many commented it out things. Also if anyone has an idea why the navbar extends past the page making that light blue column to the right happen please let me know too.

Comment: The watch is not vertically centered for me in desktop view. Could you please create a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on something like [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/new#), which shows both the desired view and undesired view? I have a feeling that the problem is in line 114, where you're setting a `height` of `100vh` on `.device-container` in a media query of `768px`, but can't be sure without being able to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `100%` on a floating box will not make it `100%` of parent height, as you'd expect. Your best solution, from where I see it, would be to use

```
header .row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Of course, this means you'll need to lose the huge top padding on the `<h1>`, so it actually centers. If you're happy with how it looks on desktop, just wrap my suggestion in a `@media` query.

There's one more thing I'd note: you seem to use `col-xl-*` classes, which don't exist in Bootstrap, but you seem to miss the `col-xs-*` ones. Is this intentional? If not, do replace them.

Here's a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/jccqz1m7/) with what I could make from the code you posted.

Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: Yeah it was my display/align-items that was messed up for media query 768 thanks!